# string assigned to cell is empty, but not a when assigned to a message box?

Tags: vba, excel

This is my first post. I have a macro which loops through each series in a chart and is supposed to print the series formula into a worksheet column.

An error is displayed as the cell value is returned as is empty, even though the string variable (form_string) isn't. It seems that printing form_string to a message box works fine. I have tried all variations of assigning the string to a cell or a range but none seem to work.

```
Sub ChartSeriesForms()

   Dim x As Series
   Dim form_counter As Integer
   Dim form_string As String

   form_counter = 1
   For Each x In Charts(1).SeriesCollection
            form_string = x.Formula
            'MsgBox form_string
            Worksheets("SeriesFormula").Cells(form_counter,1).Value = form_string
            form_counter = form_counter + 1
    Next

End Sub
```

Any ideas, that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that `x.Formula` returns a string in the form

```
=SERIES([Series Name],[X Values],[Y Values],[Plot Order])
```

When you write this to a cell Excel tries to interpret it as a Worksheet formula, which is invalid.

If you just want to see the formula as text in the cell, prepend a `'` ie

```
Worksheets("SeriesFormula").Cells(form_counter,1).Value = "'" & form_string
```